# Manually Running Shell Script for sending new files notification emails

Tags: linux, bash, shell

this is just for learning purpose. (don't consider inotify)

what if we want to develop a bash shell script which compare file list of previous run and current run, when ever we run the script manually and email file name file size time of new files only.

Answer (score 1):

The best that I can suggest is to find the tools that you need to do you specific work.
e.g. ls -l combined with awk, use mail or any other mailing tool, etc.
The idea is to use standard tools to accomplish your mission.
Don't compile your own code, just use standard tools in your script. Most of the things that you need are already there.